# Fetch Google Now data

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-now

In my "Good morning"-app I would like to display the estimated time to work, the weather and the temperature before showing my own content.

Is there a way to fetch that information from Google Now?
I have everything I want there but can't seem to find a way to transfer it to my app.

Comment: I am also thinking about same thing but if no way for do that !
You have to get data by reverse engineering through determine adress of variable value in memory

Comment: Google Direction API gives estimated time and Yahoo Weather API(many more weather APIs) gives weather.